# No se puede insertar el valor NULL en la columna 'Valor Columna'

Tags: sql

---

```
Create TRIGGER [dbo].[TG_GirasDelete] ON [dbo].[Giras] AFTER delete
AS 
BEGIN
    DECLARE
    @Id_Bitacora int , 
    @Fecha_Movimiento smalldatetime, 
    @Tipo_Movimiento char(1), 
    @Num_Linea int, 
    @Nombre_Columna varchar(50), 
    @Tipo_Data_Columna varchar(50), 
    @Valor_Columna varchar(500) ,

@Errores int = 0

Begin transaction Fn_Siguiente_Id
-------------------------------------------
-- PASO 1 : registra Bitacora_Encabezado --
-------------------------------------------
SET @Id_Bitacora = dbo.Fn_Siguiente_Id ( 'Bitacoras_Encabezado' )
SET @Fecha_Movimiento = GETDATE()
SET @Tipo_Movimiento = 'D'
INSERT dbo.Bitacoras_Encabezado VALUES ( @Id_Bitacora , @Fecha_Movimiento , @Tipo_Movimiento )
IF @@ERROR <> 0
    SET @Errores = @Errores + 1

----------------------------------------
```

Este es el **error**:

> Msg 515, Level 16, State 2, Procedure TG_GirasDelete, Line 33 [Batch
>   Start Line 25] Cannot insert the value NULL into column
>   'Valor_Columna', table 'UMCA_Giras.dbo.Bitacora_Detalle'; column does
>   not allow nulls. INSERT fails. The statement has been terminated.

Comment: Disculpa, ¿podrías editar la pregunta para indicar cuál es tu duda? Y si añades la estructura de la tabla e información complementaria, será más fácil que alguien pueda ayudarte.

Comment: la duda seria el mensaje de error, como podria soluciarno

Comment: Pues el error dice muy claro: la columna de la tabla (cuya estructura no nos muestras) tiene un constraint not null, por lo que no permite valores nulos.

Comment: el problema es que no estoy insertando datos nulos

Comment: el problema es que quisiera mostrar mas, pero el proyecto es grande comparado con esta plataforma

Comment: La única instrucción que podría provocar ese error, del código que nos muestras, es: `INSERT dbo.Bitacoras_Encabezado VALUES(...`, habría que ver cual es la estructura de la tabla `Bitacoras_Encabezado`. Por otro lado el mensaje de error dice claramente que es en la tabla `Bitacora_Detalle`, no en la `Bitacoras_Encabezado`. Sospecho que hay parte del trigger que no has compartido.

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que editar la tabla, la columna 'Valor Columna' es NOT NULL, puedes probar lo siguiente:

```
alter table"nombre_tabla" drop valor_columna
go
alter table"nombre_tabla" add valor_columna varchar(500) Null
go
```

Lo que estoy haciendo con este código es borrar la columna valor_columna y volviendola a crear con el NULL habilitado, si tienes valores en la columna, se borran, asi que ten cuidado